ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider }) function causing react webpage to not load on safari browsers
Im building a wallet using CRA (react-js) that lets users see and interact with their DOT and KSM cryptocurrencies (among others) and so far everything works. However, my react webpage fails to load on Safari browsers and instead shows a blank white page. Ive narrowed it down to this specific function i use in my code that initializes a connection to a provider to load the balance data:
const wallet = await this.generate_dot_wallet(seed)
const address = wallet.dot_address
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://polkadot-rpc.publicnode.com');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider }); <---------- this line right here is causing safari to fail to load the entire page and show a blank white page.
await api.isReady;
const existential_deposit = await this.get_existential_dot_deposit(api)
const address_balance = await this.get_dot_balance(address, api)
await api.disconnect()

Now i read somewhere that safari is pretty sensitive to errors so i looked at its logs in the safari console and found something like this:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

when i expand the error, it shows me the error is in this specific line in a bundle.js file:
static with(Types) {
let definition;
// eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
const setDefinition = d => definition = d;
return class extends Enum {
  static { <---------------------this token right here is causing the error
    const keys = Array.isArray(Types) ? Types : Object.keys(Types);
    const count = keys.length;
    const asKeys = new Array(count);
    const isKeys = new Array(count);
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      const name = (0,_polkadot_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.stringPascalCase)(keys[i]);
      asKeys[i] = `as${name}`;
      isKeys[i] = `is${name}`;
    }

My webapp is working fine on Chrome, Firefox and the other browsers but failing on all safari browsers (both MacOS and iOS). The issue popped up a few weeks ago and since this is a library issue, there isn't much i can do other than disable support for DOT and KSM until the issue is resolved.
Safari: Version 15.5 (17613.2.7.1.8), NPM version: 9.6.7, Node version: 18.17.1 and the polkadot.js dependency version in my package.json:
"@polkadot/api": "^14.0.1",
"@polkadot/util-crypto": "^13.1.1",
"@polkadot/wasm-crypto": "^7.3.2",

and my import statements look like this:
import { Keyring, ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api'; 
import { waitReady, } from '@polkadot/wasm-crypto';
import { encodeAddress, decodeAddress } from '@polkadot/util-crypto';


unrelated, safari also doesnt work when you set Buffer manually (if youre using bip39 functions like mnemonicToSeedSync) like this: window.Buffer = window.Buffer || Buffer

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you're building a new app, you should absolutely use PAPI instead of Polkadot-js api. It's much more light-weight, is type safe, has much better support, and is future proof, unlike polkadot-js api.
